# Implementing rint() in x86-64

Tags: visual-c++, math, floating-point, sse

MSVC 2012 doesn't have the rint() function. For 32-bit, I'm using the following:

```
double rint(double x) {
    __asm {
        fld x
        frndint
    }
}
```

This doesn't work in x64. There's _mm_round_sd() but that requires SSE4. What is an efficient preferrably branchless way of getting the same behavior?

Comment: If you care little enough about the number of instructions as to be flexible whether a candidate it actually branchless, a few C implementations for rounding a float to the nearest integer are at http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/05/02/nearbyintf1 and following. Adapting these to double-precision is a matter of adjusting a couple of constants. (Note: the first implementation does not round to nearest-even, but it rounds to the nearest integer, and only differs from nearest-even for ties).

Answer (score 2):

rint 64-bit mode

```
#include <emmintrin.h>

static inline double rint (double const x) {
    return (double)_mm_cvtsd_si32(_mm_load_sd(&x));
}
```

See Agner Fog's [Optimizing C++ manual](http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_cpp.pdf) for lrint

32-bit mode

```
// Example 14.19
static inline int lrint (double const x) { // Round to nearest integer
    int n;
    #if defined(__unix__) || defined(__GNUC__)
    // 32-bit Linux, Gnu/AT&T syntax:
    __asm ("fldl %1 \n fistpl %0 " : "=m"(n) : "m"(x) : "memory" );
    #else
    // 32-bit Windows, Intel/MASM syntax:
    __asm fld qword ptr x;
    __asm fistp dword ptr n;
    #endif
    return n;
}
```

64-bit mode

```
// Example 14.21. // Only for SSE2 or x64
#include <emmintrin.h>

static inline int lrint (double const x) {
    return _mm_cvtsd_si32(_mm_load_sd(&x));
}
```

**Edit:**
I just realized that this method will limit the values to to +/- 2^31.  If you want a version with a larger range with SSE2 it's complicated (but easy with SSE4.1).  See the round function in Agner Fog's Vector Class in the file vectorf128.h for an example.