# Can't get modf() to work in multithread

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I have implemented two different functions to round a double figure to integer.

Here is the first function

```
static inline int round_v1(double value) 
{
    int t;
    __asm
    {
        fld value;
        fistp t;
    }
    return t;
}
```

Here is the second function

```
static inline int round_v2(double value) 
{
    double intpart, fractpart;
    fractpart = modf(value, &intpart);
    if ((fabs(fractpart) != 0.5) || ((((int)intpart) % 2) != 0))
        return (int)(value + (value >= 0 ? 0.5 : -0.5));
    else
        return (int)intpart;
}
```

Both functions can work well in single thread, but the second one cannot work int multi-thread (using openMP). The program just crash when I use the second one.
Here is the main code where the `round_v1` or `round_v2` function is called.

```
void
BilateralFilter_Invoker::doFilter() const
{
    if (!src || !dst) return;
    int i, j;
    int src_width = width + (radius << 1);

    omp_set_num_threads(2);
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (i = 0; i < height; ++i)
    {
        unsigned char* pSrc = src + (i+radius)*src_step + radius;
        unsigned char* pDst = dst + i*dst_step;
        for (j = 0; j < width; ++j)
        {
            float sum = 0.f, wsum = 0.f;
            int  val0 = pSrc[j];

            for (int k = 0; k < maxk; ++k)
            {
                int val = pSrc[j + space_offset[k]];
                float w = space_weight[k] * color_weight[std::abs(val-val0)];
                sum  += val * w;
                wsum += w;
            }

            //pDst[j] = (unsigned char)round_v2(sum / wsum);
            pDst[j] = (unsigned char)round_v1(sum / wsum);
        }
    }
}
```

the variables `src`, `dst`, `height`, `width`, `src_step`, `dst_step`, `radius`, `maxk`, `space_offset`, `space_weight`, `color_weight` are member variables of class BilateralFilter_Invoker.

I respectively call `round_v1` and `round_v2` for test and program crashes only when `round_v2` was called. I wonder whether the `modf(double, double*)` function may cause this problem. For further test, I comment this line

```
fractpart = modf(value, &intpart);
```

and replace it by

```
fractpart = intpart = value;
```

I run the program again and it did not crash again. I have no idea whether `modf(double, double*)` causes this problem. Or maybe there is something wrong in my code causes the problem rather than the `modf(double, double*)` function.

Notice that The operating system I use is Windows7 and the compiler is VC10.

Comment: Which operating system? Which compiler? Which optimization flags? IMHO `modf` should be thread safe, because it is specified to be thread-safe in [modf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/modf.3.html)

Comment: You should compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -pthread -g`) and **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, the operating system is Windows7 and the compiler is VC10

Comment: I think *your assembler code* is causing the problem. It needs an FWAIT.

Comment: @EJP, the assembler code is good, I test ```round_v1(double)``` a lot and it work fine.

Comment: If you really think `modf()` is the culprit, where is your test that only uses `modf()`? Prove. Eliminate. Verify. I suggest you look up FWAIT and the assembler code generated by `modf()` before you debate this further.

Comment: @EJP, sorry and my bad, I forgot to add "//" before the line pDst[j] = (unsigned char)round_v2(sum / wsum); and I edit it again. Actually, I test ```round_v1``` and ```round_v2``` respectively. It's my bad to describe the question unclearly.

Comment: It is also your responsibility to test your assertions properly, rather than blame a function that has been in existence for forty years ahead of your own code, with zero evidence.

Comment: @EJP,Hi~I think you misunderstand me. What I mean is when I edit this question in stackoverflow website, I forgot to add "//" before the line. Actually, when I do the tests I only use ```modf()``` and program still crash. I have re-edited my question and make the question more clear. I just want to figure out what cause the problem  and I don't blame the function.

Comment: Try `#pragma omp parallel for private(j)`.

Answer (score 4):

You have made the most common mistake with OpenMP on SO. The iterator of your inner loop needs to be made private.  You can either do

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(j)
```

or use loop initial declarations

```
for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
```

In fact, since you never use `i` or `j` outside of the loops they apply to there is no reason to declare them C89 style outside of the loops.

Comment: As you say, the non-private inner loop causes this problem. Thanks~

Comment: @CJZ, was there something more you wanted?

Comment: @CJZ, this may interest you [implementing-rint-in-x86-64](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21605289/2542702).